# Return value of pbinom in function always 0 or 1

Tags: r

I´m trying to integrate pbinom in a function, but I only get 1 or 0 in return.

```
> PWert <- function(n, k, p0, side){
+   ifelse(side=="greater", return(1-pbinom(k-1,n,p0)), return(pbinom(k,n,p0)))
+ }
> PWert(6,10,0.5,"greater")
[1] 0
> 1-pbinom(6-1,10,0.5)
[1] 0.3769531
```

My guess is that the function somehow rounds the value up/down to 1 or 0. But I can´t really see why? I´ve also tried it without ifelse, but still the same.

Comment: In the function it looks like you're running `1-pbinom(10-1,6,0.5)`.

Comment: ouch, yep that was it!

Answer (score 2):

The `ifelse` function is not used for control flow. You could write:

```
if (side=='greater') 
   return(1-pbinom(k-1,n,p0)) 
else 
   return(pbinom(k,n,p0)))
```

Interestingly, you *could* use the `ifelse` function to vectorize your function by removing the `return`:

```
PWert <- function(n, k, p0, side)
  ifelse(side=="greater", 1-pbinom(k-1,n,p0), pbinom(k,n,p0))
```

Now you can supply a vector of `side`. If you want a bunch of values some "greater" and some not.